# VBA Copy Cells from a Worksheet to a New One with Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

It seems I have two lines of problematic codes. Without them, the codes can run well, with them included, I will get a Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

What I basically want to do is to send a command with conditions from workbook C to copy a range of cells from a workbook A to workbook B, my codes as below:

And please see the two problematic lines I marked. It looked perfectly fine to me but somehow VBA won't execute it. Can anyone explain to me why is this so?

I seem to bump into similar problems as long as I am messing with lots of workbooks, so I guess this is a general problem I have when dealing with multiple workbooks and is not limited to just copying cells...

```
Sub TrySaveAs()

  Dim wkb0 As Workbook
  Set wkb0 = ThisWorkbook
  Dim wkb1 As Workbook
  Dim wkb2 As Workbook

  Dim i As Integer
  i = 2

  Do Until IsEmpty(wkb0.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1))

    Dim full_path As String
    full_path = C:\something\something.xlsx

    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=somename)
    wkb1.SaveAs Filename:=full_path

    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=someothername)
    Dim last_row As Integer
    last_row = wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, 5)).Copy <--------problematic
    wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, 5)).Paste <--------problematic
    wkb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    wkb1.Close SaveChanges:=True

    i = i + 1

  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Check your wkb2 to see if it opens successfully, and if the worksheet's name are correct / exist / not hidden.  Also, full_path's value needs ""

Comment: i think they are OK. i just crossed them out here to avoid complications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

`wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(last_row, 5).Address).Copy`

and

`wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(last_row, 5).Address).PasteSpecial`

**edit**

To understand better why take a look at this, with the comments

```
Sub hello()
Dim rr1 As Range
Dim rr2, rr3 As Range

Debug.Print Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3)).Address(External:=False)
Set rr1 = Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3))
Debug.Print rr1.Parent.Name & "'!" & rr1.Address(External:=False)
MsgBox rr1.Parent.Name & "'!" & rr1.Address(External:=False)
'notice it says "Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$3

Worksheets(2).Activate
Set rr2 = Cells(1, 1) 'if we dont qualify Cells, with a range object, it defaults to cells of ActiveSheet
Set rr3 = Cells(3, 3)

Debug.Print Range(rr2, rr3).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(rr2, rr3).Address(External:=False)
MsgBox Range(rr2, rr3).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(rr2, rr3).Address(External:=False)
'notice it says "Sheet2'!$A$1:$C$3, because that is the current ActiveSheet

Worksheets(3).Activate
Set rr2 = Cells(1, 1) 'if we dont qualify Cells with a range object, it defaults to cells of ActiveSheet
Set rr3 = Cells(3, 3)
Debug.Print Range(rr2, rr3).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(rr2, rr3).Address(External:=False)
MsgBox Range(rr2, rr3).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(rr2, rr3).Address(External:=False)
'notice it says "Sheet3'!$A$1:$C$3, because that is the current ActiveSheet

On Error GoTo theError
Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Range(rr1, rr2).Address
MsgBox Worksheets(1).Range(rr1, rr2).Address
theError: Debug.Print "Error because ranges rr1 and rr2 are cells of Worksheet(3), not Worksheet(1)"

Debug.Print Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Parent.Name & "'!" & _
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Address(External:=False)
MsgBox Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Parent.Name & "'!" & _
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Address(External:=False)
'notice it says "Sheet3'!$A$1:$C$3, because that is the current ActiveSheet
'Moral of story you cannot do Worksheets(1).range(cells(a,b),cells(c,d)) because
'cannot guarantee Cells refer to Worksheet(1)


'If you really want to refer to unqualified Cells, one way is to mimic the Excel
'range syntax by grabbing the cell address
Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(3, 3).Address).Parent.Name & "'!" & _
Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(3, 3).Address).Address(External:=False)

MsgBox Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(3, 3).Address).Parent.Name & "'!" & _
Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(3, 3).Address).Address(External:=False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing it worked! But can you kindly tell me why my code didn't work just then as well so that I can know the reason and avoid it next time?

Comment: And one extra question too... I try your code but with Paste instead of PasteSpecial, i will then have error 438, how come i must use PasteSpecial in this occasion??

Comment: @BoscoTsin thanks. Glad it worked for you. `Paste` works differently. It works in conjunction with the clipboard, and also makes use of selected ranges (which is why you see it if you recorded a macro). Because you copy the range using `Copy` method, there is no range selection (selecting anything in VBA is hopelessly demonic, and you should *almost* never have to `select` anything). `PasteSpecial` is a `Range` method. So (usually) just work as expected...but this is really a separate question.

Comment: @BoscoTsin Please remember to mark **an** answer as accepted, so others seeking the same help may find an answer.

Comment: @BoscoTsin As Degaustaf says, some things in VBA will implicitly assume you are referring to `ActiveSheet`, and `Cells` is one of those statements. `Cells` should be thought of as referring to a parent range object. When no parent object is specified, `ActiveSheet` is the default.

Comment: ok, so i guess somehow my Cells inside ranges are unspecified and god knows what VBA was assuming. that could be my problem... anyway thanks and i will mark is as answered

Comment: @BoscoTsin I updated my answer with another `Sub` so you can understand what is going on better. It is not "somehow", it is how the `.Cells` property works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273%28v=office.15%29.aspx . Not only God knows, but you do too, now: VBA assumes an unqualified `Cells` refers to `ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 1):

You have hit upon a hidden reference to `ActiveSheet`.  An unqualified call to `Range` that is passed a string or an unqualified reference to `Cells` defaults to `Activesheet.Range` and `ActiveSheet.Cells`.  So your first problematic line becomes

```
 wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, 5)).Copy
```

And, this will error out, unless `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)` is in `wkb2.Worksheets("RAW")`.

The correct way to do this, so that it doesn't error out is to put the sheet reference on the call to `Cells`, and not on the call to `Range`:

```
Range(wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Cells(1, 1), _
    wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Cells(last_row, 5)).Copy
```

In reference to @Rusan Kax's answer, `Cells(1, 1).Address` defaults to `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Address` which becomes the string `A1`.  And the call

```
wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1:...").Copy
```

is valid syntax.

Comment: thanks Degustaf your version works for me too. you mean its valid syntax and somehow working for @Rusan Kax's code, but theoretically not too right because the area i referred to is not exactly the same one i want to refer to, but that is the address range i somehow need anyway... am i understanding it right?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
wkb2.Worksheets("RAW").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, 5)).Copy destination:= _
wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, 5))
```

I think `.Paste` pastes the contents of the clipboard to the specified range

Comment: Hi Barry, I just tried your code but it doesn't work. Error 1004 still. Any ideas about that?